# org-mode figures always centered

Tags: org-mode, org-export

As of now, org-mode always adds a *\centering* into the Latex export for figures. This makes my figures appear centered. But I want them to be alligned to the left. For tables, some suggested using *:center nil*. But there is no such thing for figures. Someone else suggested modifying an elisp variable but I looked and there is no such variable. If I add *:float nil* then *\centering* is removed but this ignores captions as well. So how can I make Latex export not add \centering before \includegraphics by default? I want to retain captions.

If I manually edit resulting tex file and remove *\centering*, I get my images as intended. But this time caption stays centered, only the image moves.

Answer (score 6):

In `org-mode` 8.3 or later, this is controlled by the variable `org-latex-images-centered`:

> When non-nil, images are centered.

The default is `t`; you want to set it to `nil`.  This can be done either by setting it globally in your Emacs config: `(setq org-latex-images-centered nil)` or by using a `BIND` option in each org file where you want this setting:

```
#+BIND: org-latex-images-centered nil
```

In the latter case you have to set `org-export-allow-bind-keywords` to `t` in your Emacs config to allow the `BIND` keyword to do anything.

To set this per figure (or table) you can set latex [attributes](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-specific-attributes.html).  Adding

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :center nil
```

will suppress the centering for that float only.

For tables there is a corresponding variable `org-latex-tables-centered` that behaves the same way.

Personally I recommend the `BIND` version as it makes the document more portable and reproducible, especially if you have co-authors.

Comment: I set it to *nil* but the outcome didn't change. Produced tex file still has *\centering* embedded.

Comment: It works for me in Emacs 26.0.50.2, Org mode 9.0.3. Do you have different version?  I'm editing in another method you can try.

Comment: I am still using emacs25 and my org-mode is 8.2. I will consider upgrading.

Comment: 25 is the current stable version; it's best to stick with that unless you like betas.  Probably updating org-mode is enough.

Comment: @meguli A little searching seems to show this variable first appeared in org 8.3.

Comment: Yes, I updated to org-mode 9. But still, setting that variable nil did not solve the problem. It still centers the image. I need this so badly because I am using org-mode to output margin figure. If they are centered, much of the figure is lost in the margin. I need to align it to the left. Packages like sidenotes offers me a workaround but I am looking for pure org-mode solutions. That way, HTML and PDF exports work well together.

Comment: @meguli Have you tried the `BIND` version?  That's the one I use.

Comment: Yes, but no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50985/discussion-between-erikstokes-and-meguli).